# trouble with graphics card and other partitions after reinstall of windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, partitioning, graphics-card, grub

I recently reinstalled Windows 7 and have found myself in a pile of problems that I can't find any record of anywhere. If this is the wrong place to post this type of problem I apologize.

When I first logged in (after thirty successive reboots for updating and bumping my resolution up to HD settings) I noticed that my display didn't stretch to meet the edges of my screen with a black border around everything. Poking around reveals that my computer isn't detecting my graphics card. The reinstallation didn't involve any poking around in the hardware so I doubt it fell out during the process. No clue what could cause this.

Then I tried to access my Ubuntu partition so I could look up what my graphics card was to post this, I found that when I selected Ubuntu in the Windows Boot Launcher it then took me to GRUB as expected but with different options than I remember. As shown below:

```
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.8.0-29-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.8.0-29-generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.35-22-generic (on /dev/sda5)
Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.35-22-generic (recovery mode) (on /dev/sda5)
```

Which is really interesting because it looks like I have 2 Ubuntu partitions when in reality I only have 1. Additionally, Windows isn't appearing which is weird. Also, the top boots into 12.04 (which I've never downloaded, I've owned 10.10 and 13.10) and doesn't accept any of the passwords which I use. Alternatively the other one (which I thought might work since /dev/sda5 is the partition I used for installing the Ubuntu partition) boots into 10.10 which is also weird because I thought I removed 10.10 from my computer when I replaced it with 13.10.

Sorry for the long rambling question(s). All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My hunch is that, in re-installing Windows, the Windows installer has adjusted your partition table, so that what had been `/dev/sdaX` is now `/dev/sdaY`. This in turn will throw off all sorts of things. For instance, the Windows boot manager might be launching an old forgotten version of GRUB that's been lurking on one of your Linux partitions unused for some time. Likewise, any absolute partition references within GRUB will be wrong.

As to booting Ubuntu 12.04, if it's booting, it *must* be installed on the computer. If you bought your computer used, perhaps the previous owner installed it and you didn't remove it; or maybe you *did* install it but have forgotten about it. I think it's just a tad unlikely that the Windows installer set up Ubuntu 12.04. ;)

I have a few ideas about fixes:

- Repair it within Windows by mucking about with `bcdedit` or using [EasyBCD.](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) This will preserve the Windows boot manager as the primary one, which I gather was the case before this began; but there will be some guesswork as to how to do it -- in particular, you'll need to guess what partition holds the GRUB that you want to use.
- Use [Super GRUB2 Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/) to detect your working GRUB installations and boot to your preferred version of Linux. You can then install GRUB to the computer's MBR via the `grub-install` command. (This approach assumes you're booting in BIOS mode. If you've got a newer computer, it may be booting in EFI mode, which will require using the CD-R or USB flash drive version of [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) rather than Super GRUB2 Disk.)
- Run the Ubuntu [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool. In theory, this will fix everything automatically, setting GRUB as the default boot loader. In practice, it *usually* works, but sometimes it doesn't help, and on rare occasions it can make matters worse.

Concerning your video issues, you may need to download and install a video driver for your video chipset or card from its manufacturer (probably AMD/ATI, Nvidia, or Intel). I'm not an expert on Windows video problems, though, so I'll leave it to others to provide more suggestions. Knowing more about your video hardware will help such people, though, so I recommend you edit your question to include those details.

Comment: Boot Repair worked like a charm (although I have 2 listings for windows). I'm not sure if I should wait for an answer for the graphics problem or make another posting.